# run-time error '424' in visual basis 6

Tags: vb6

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With supGrid
        .ColWidth(0) = 3000
        .ColWidth(1) = 1500
        .ColWidth(2) = 3000
        .ColWidth(3) = 4000
        .ColWidth(4) = 1400
    End With
    Call grd_Data_Loader
End Sub
```

I kinda forgot how to code in vb6.0. What should I do. When vb6 say there is an error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't recognise "supGrid". Have you mistyped the name of your control?

I recommend changing the vb6 settings so that vb6 tells you about this earlier. On Tools-Options, switch on Require Variable Declarations.